# Laravel : Update Database using Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I have build a shopping cart..Where I tried to update database using ajax..when I will update the quantity, it will reflect the database immediately..

for that i used the following View:

```
 @foreach($carts as $row)
 <input type="hidden" class="cat_id" value="{{$row->id}}"/>
<input type="number" class="quantity" value="{{$row->no_of_items}}" name="qty" maxlength="3" max="999" min="1" /> &times;${{$row->p_price}}
 @endforeach
```

Here is the Ajax Part:

```
$(".quantity").change(updateCart);

    function updateCart(){
        var qty = parseInt($(this).val());
        var cat_id = parseInt($('.cat_id').val());
        console.log(cat_id);

        $.ajaxSetup({
                                headers: {
                              'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                            }
                             });

          $.ajax({  
                            url:"{{url('cart/update/{cat_id}/{qty}')}}",  
                            method:"POST",  
                            data:{cat_id:cat_id, qty:qty},                              
                               success: function( data ) {
                         // console.log(data);
                        }
                       });
    }
```

Route

Route::post('cart/update/{cat_id}/{qty}','ProductController@cartUpdate');

And the controller part :

```
public function cartUpdate($cat_id, $qty)
    {
        $cart = Cart::find($cat_id);
        $product = Product::find($cart->product_id);
        $cart->no_of_items = Input::get('qty'); 
        $cart->price = $product->price * $cart->no_of_items;
        $cart->save();
    }
```

- I have product_id in carts table
  The problem I'm facing is whenever i tried to update the Quantity i saw error on console mode:

  ErrorException in ProductController.php 
  Trying to get property of non-object

when i dd() the cat_id i see null value or same for all the curt..what could be the possible? thanks

Comment: Look at browser's devtools network. In the request must be your ids. So you can check ajax-request. I think error happened there.

Comment: In network when i dd(cat_id) i see null

Comment: No-no, just look at request. For example: http://imgur.com/a4E1YWt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is you are not passing the **`cat_id`** and **`qty`** via the url and is passed via ajax post request

```
$.ajax({
    url:"{{url('cart/update/{cat_id}/{qty}')}}",  
    method:"POST",  
    data:{
         cat_id : cat_id,
         qty: qty
    },                              
    success: function( data ) {
        // console.log(data);
    }
});
```

hence the **`$cat_id`** and **`$qty`** is **`null`** in the Controller, so you need to change the code in your controller as

```
    public function cartUpdate($cat_id, $qty)
    {
        $cart = Cart::find(Input::get('cat_id'));
        $product = Product::find($cart->product_id);
        $cart->no_of_items = Input::get('qty'); 
        $cart->price = $product->price * $cart->no_of_items;
        $cart->save();
    }
```

Comment: But i get same same cart id for all in the list from view page..Besides it not updated anything ..

Comment: Change this in your javascript code **`var cat_id = parseInt($('.cat_id').val());`** to **`var cat_id = parseInt($(this).prev().val());`**

Comment: When you inspect the **`cat_id`** in the DOM? What value are you seeing?

Comment: in foreach loop everytime same cat_id printed

Comment: Do you get different **`cat_id`** when you do **`dd($carts)`** outside foreach loop

Comment: in console.log() whenever i choose the quantity it should print different different cat_id right?
but it's printing same for all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138514/discussion-between-linktoahref-and-user57).

Answer (score 1):

Try This Way:

```
@foreach($carts as $row)
 <input type="hidden" class="cat_id" name="cat_id" value="{{$row->id}}"/>
 <!--Add name="cat_id" AS Attribute -->
<input type="number" class="quantity{{$row->id}}" value="{{$row->no_of_items}}" name="qty" maxlength="3" max="999" min="1" /> &times;${{$row->p_price}}
@endforeach
```

And Ajax Part :

```
 @foreach($carts as $row)
    $(".quantity{{$row->id}}").change(updateCart);
 @endforeach

 function updateCart(){
    var qty = parseInt($(this).val());
    var cat_id = parseInt($('.cat_id').val());
    console.log(cat_id);

      $.ajax({ 
                        headers: {
                          'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                        },
                        url:'cart/update',  
                        method:"POST",  
                        data:{
                            cat_id:cat_id, 
                            qty:qty
                        },                              
                        success: function( data ) {
                     // console.log(data);
                    }
                   });
}
```

Comment: same thing coming ..In foreach loop everytime same cat_id get printed..
and value also not getting updated

Comment: check ur array $carts, and you also misspelt "@endforeach"